# sum of manhattan distances between user input numbers in a 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, user-input

my program is a 2d  square array in java, which needs to read user input numbers and calculate the manhattan distance between them. I'm struggling with this and don't know how to do it (don't even know how to do this for two different numbers). 
(The array is a square of numbers from 0 to sth the user inputs. The sum starts at the first input number, calculates the distance to the second input, then from the second to third and so on and so on). 
Example if the side of the square array is 6 (That means that the first row would contain numbers 0 to 5, second 6 to 11 etc.):
(Also, the number of how many numbers the user is going to insert is also a part of the program, but I've already done that. So let's say that this number is 4 - the program will want the user to input 4 numbers, between which we want the distance to be calculated). The input is : 4 12 24 6
Output should be : 11 (sum of manhattan distances between these numbers)

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Provide more details in the question, like a sample of input and output.

Comment: I edited the question. Any better?

Comment: The distance is defined on points, is the input just two points (4, 12) and (24,6)?

Comment: no, literally four numbers separated by space. here, this is what the array looks like : 
0   1   2    3   4   5
6   7   8    9  10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35

Comment: Ugh, sorry it doesn't want to appear right. The rows are from 0 to 5, then the 6 is in the second row and up to 11, 12 is in the third row and so on and so on

Comment: Manhattan distance calculates distance between points, so a pair of coordinates, not single numbers.

Comment: so, could I do it any differently? this is an assignment so I have some rules about the inputs and they strictly cannot be points but just numbers.

Comment: Manhattan distance is defined on 2 dimensions. Either you took the notes wrong, or the person who made the assignments needs to recheck their stuff.